# How to check the part of a string withing two specified words in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a xml, I'm treating it as a single string.

```
<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>
```

Now I want to check the part of the string between two tags. 
For example `<TRANSACTION>` and `</TRANSACTION>`. 
How can it be done in sql server.

Comment: Also show us some more sample data and also specify the expected result. Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>', CHARINDEX('<TRANSACTION>', '<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>')+Len('<TRANSACTION>')
, CHARINDEX('</TRANSACTION>','<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>') - CHARINDEX('<TRANSACTION>', '<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>')-Len('</TRANSACTION>'))
```

Comment: I've done it already but thanks a lot this solution is also working very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX)= '<TRANSACTION> some text here </TRANSACTION>';

SELECT CAST(@Str AS XML).value('(/TRANSACTION)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')
```

If your database field is already a XML type, CAST as XML is not required.

Comment: This one is also fantastic. In fact better one than those which i have got